# Build PJSIP with video support on Windows 7, with MinGW

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mingw, sdl, pjsip

I'm trying to build PJSIP with video support for Windows OS, on my Windows 7 PC by using MinGW.
Following the official guide from PJSIP:
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf#VideoSupportfor2.0andabove

Building PJSIP without video support works as expected for me.

- I'm using the latest PJSIP 2.2.1 from SVN
- SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz (MinGW 32/64-bit)
- ffmpeg-20140805-git-de41798-win32-dev

I have added "#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1" in the config_site.h file
and I'm building PJSIP with the following options:
./configure --with-ffmpeg="/c/PJSIP/ffmpeg" --with-sdl="/c/PJSIP/SDL"

but I have the following compilation error for SDL:

```
c:/PJSIP/SDL/lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function `console_main':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_win
dows_main.c:140: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjsua2-test-i686-pc-mingw32] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/PJSIP/trunk/pjsip/build'
make[1]: *** [pjsua2-test-i686-pc-mingw32] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/PJSIP/trunk/pjsip/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The same error is available with SDL-2.0.2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to get it to build with MinGW 64bit. I suppose you could apply my patch and build it for MinGW 32bit as well. However, I mostly work with 64bit. I maintain a distribution for my company, which is open source, called [mingle](https://github.com/onepremise/Mingle). I recently added pjsip when I saw your post and decided to give it a shot with our distribution. I was able to build yasm, sdl, ffmpeg, and pjsip. pjsip did require a [few small changes](https://github.com/onepremise/Mingle/blob/master/patches/pjproject/2.2.1/pjproject-mingw.patch) to build all the way through. You are welcome to download and try the patch. I also added the build procedures to mingle. If you have problems building individually, you may [get mingle off github](https://github.com/onepremise/Mingle) and let it build the component and all dependencies for you. After running setup, run 'setup -b -c' under dos administrative mode, console will come up, run mingle, select:

> mm)        Multimedia - codecs, encoders, converters, etc...

Mingle should build all dependencies, and I mean 'all', all the way up to pjsip. It will take a while. You can also [download our distribution](https://vanguard.houghtonassociates.com/browse/MINGLE-MINGLE64-191) with the dependencies prebuilt, but it's pretty large. It can save time if you have a fast connection. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved.

Modify these files:

1, pjsip\src\pjsua2-test\main.cpp

add `#include "SDL.h"`

2, pjsip-apps\src\samples\pjsua_demo.cpp

add `#include "SDL.h"`

replace `int main()` with `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`